# angular 2 *ngFor, when iterable hasn't be instantiated yet

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a couple of *ngFor loops depending on iterables which might not be instantiated yet. (e.g. they are waiting for an observable)

is there any expression like this I could use in the view?

UPDATE:
Here's the part thats throwing error

Component

```
activeLectureContent:LectureContent;
```

View

```
  <div class="filter-units">
    <div>Units</div>
    <a (click)="setUnit(i)" class="btn btn-icon-only blue filter-unit-btn" *ngFor="#unit of activeLectureContent.content; #i = index">
      <span>{{i+1}}</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**Cannot read property 'content' of undefined in [null]**

Lecture Content looks like this

```
export class LectureContent{
  constructor(
    public name:string = '',
    public filter:LectureFilter[]=[],
    public show:boolean = true,
    public hover:boolean = false,
    public content:any[]=[]
  ){}
}
```

cheers

Comment: Is this causing an error?  Often, you don't have to do anything if the iterable doesn't exist yet.

Comment: yes, that iterable contains large objects and elements inside that div need to access those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's "simply" an iterable (array, ... but not observable, promise), I think that there is nothing to do. `ngFor` will check for updates of the iterable. When the value will become not null, `ngFor` will update the corresponding content:

See this sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="#category of categories;#i=index">{{i}} - {{category.name}}</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    Observable.create((observer) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next();
      }, 2000);
    }).subscribe(() => {
      this.categories = [
        { name: 'Cat1', value: 'cat1' },
        { name: 'Cat2', value: 'cat2' },
        { name: 'Cat3', value: 'cat3' },
        { name: 'Cat4', value: 'cat4' }
      ];
    });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/J1aVclVcjJPqm1Qx9j0j?p=preview.

With beta 17, you need to replace `#` by `let`:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories;let i=index">{{i}} - (...)
```

It doesn't seem that `ngIf` with `ngFor` works well. See thisp plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/aE3umzzSZ5U9BocEE9l6?p=preview

If "iterable" is an observable or a promise, que the async pipe.

**Edit**

You could try something like that:

```
<template [ngIf]=" activeLectureContent ">
    <a (click)="setUnit(i)" class="btn btn-icon-only blue filter-unit-btn" *ngFor="#unit of activeLectureContent.content; #i = index">
      <span>{{i+1}}</span>
    </a>
</template>
```

I use the expanded syntax for ngIf since ngFor and ngIf can't be used on the same element.

Comment: Hi Thierry, i've updated my question. Maybe my iterable isn't really an simple iterable? Because it's an array inside an object that hasn't be instantiated yet? If I get you correcty, ngFor doesn't throw an error if its hooked directly to an iterable?

Comment: Hey! You need to check that activeLectureContent isn't undefined. I updated my answer. Perhaps the Elvis operator could be used: "activeLectureContent?.content". But I don't know if it works in this case (ngFor).

Comment: THANKS! Elvis really safed they day ;)

Comment: Elvis really works for activeLectureContent?.content.
however it won't work for activeLectureContent?.content[activeUnit]?.tasks
since content is an array and not an object i guess?
as for the ngIf = false, means the whole block won't be rendered at all, so any uninstantiated variables inside won't cause error.

Comment: Great! Perhaps you could try this: "activeLectureContent?.content?[activeMent].tasks"

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `ngIf` directive, so it is only rendered if `iterable` is thruthy.

```
<div *ngIf="iterable" *ngFor="let item of iterable"><div>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply, i've updated my question because i think i'm looping not directly over an iterable but rather it's an array inside an Object which hasn't be instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

Resurrecting this post as I recently had this same question.

This is a perfect case for Angular's ([safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expression-operators)).

From the docs:

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

So the example view from the question would be:

```
  <div class="filter-units">
    <div>Units</div>
    <a (click)="setUnit(i)" class="btn btn-icon-only blue filter-unit-btn" 
      *ngFor="let unit of activeLectureContent?.content; let i = index">
      <span>{{i+1}}</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Adding the ? after activeLectureContent means the ngFor will be ignored if activeLectureContent is null or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for AsyncPipe:

```
<div *ngFor="#item of iterable | async"></div>
```

It works with Observables, Promises and EventEmitters. You can get more information about it in the [guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) (chapter "*The impure AsyncPipe*") and [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html).

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply, i've updated my question because i think i'm looping not directly over an iterable but rather it's an array inside an Object which hasn't be instantiated.